# How can I make or create sounds (actually music) using PHP or Objective-C?

Tags: php, objective-c, audio

Most of the help online is about reading sound files. What I want to do is to create sound files with channels, frequencies, etc.

Is this possible with PHP? Or even with XCode and Objective-C?

Reading sound files encoded in various formats is easy, what I want to do is the opposite - create the encoding in memory and then write the sound (music) file to disk. What I want to do is to create the channels, the frequencies (and instruments) in memory and then write it to disk as mp3 (or even ogg)

Please help!

Thanks
Shaan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a `midi` file. Look for a Midi class in the language of your choice. Then if you need `mp3`, convert the `midi` to `mp3`

Comment: Please do not give broad-based generic replies which lead nowhere to the question being answered.

Comment: I tought that answer would lead you to an mp3 or ogg file starting from a notes and instruments. I found myself googling but then tought you might do that as well becaus you better know what you need. I understand now that midi does not suit your needs. Is that because it is essential for you to synthesise the waves yourself, not to use existing instruments? Can you be specific in your feedback and not generic?